# unsubscribed contacts from All Subscribers - Child Business Unit

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber, unsubscriber

I need to extract unsubscribed contacts from All Subscribers in a child Business Unit in Marketing Cloud using SQL Query.

I tried to use this code, but it didn't give me any results.

```
SELECT DateUnsubscribed, EmailAddress 
FROM _Subscribers 
WHERE Status = 'unsubscribed'
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@cmbob I've ran into this issue as well.  How it was explained to me by support is that the business unit level data view, _Subscribers, only contains records that have a different status from the parent.  So, if a records is 'active' in both the parent and child, then that record will not exist in this data view.

The best way I have found for determining the Business Unit level subscriber status is by running a Tracking Extract from the Business Unit and include 'All Subscribers' in your extract.  The resulting subscribers.txt file will contain that status relative to that business unit.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use this data view:** _BusinessUnitUnsubscribes

**Marketing Cloud documentation:** [the _BusinessUnitUnsubscribes data view](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_businessunitunsubscribes.htm&type=5)

**Query example:**

```
select BusinessUnitID,
SubscriberID,
SubscriberKey, UnsubDateUTC, 
UnsubReason
from _BusinessUnitUnsubscribes
where businessUnitId = '12345678'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can absolutely do that using the _subscribers system data view.
But since you are running the query in Child BU, you need to use
**ENT._Subscribers** instead of just _Subscribers

Small correction see above

Comment: Note that this will return the status of the subscribers held at the Parent Business Unit - not the child business unit.

Comment: @AnonWonderer As far as I know The AllSubscribers are maintained at the account level.AllSubscribers List is the same across all child Business Units and parent Business unit

Comment: The multi-org is enabled in our marketing cloud account and if I use ENT._Subscribers in the query, the results is the same of the query configured in the Corporate Business Unit in order to extract the 'unsubscribed' contacts from All Subscribers .